# Software centre shows no app found

Tags: software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 for the first time. Software center shows only the apps that were installed by default. When I tried to install vlc, playforubuntu or any other app, it show no app found. 
I have also tried using terminal but not successful.

[image: Software Center searching for VLC]

---

As requested in comments, images of software home page:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the Homepage image of the Software center? It might help.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing packages repositories content. Try running this in console and whatever shows up after that:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Could you please elaborate on your answer? As it currently stands, it's quite short, and adding details on where to enter it and why you think it might solve the problem the OP is facing can enrich your answer.

Comment: This is what showing after I entered the command sudo apt update.

Comment: "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?"

Comment: That means another proccess is using the, how I call it "the directory of the update". Try to close everything that could be using it or reboot the computer. Rebooting always fixes this problem for me